# Discover if a JavaScript payload ran successfully or not

Tags: javascript, http, lua

I am using Lua with the HTTP library and I am creating a script that will test for XSS
This is the payload i'm using

```js
<image/src/onerror=prompt(8)>
```

Now the script will do an HTTP request to the website and adding the payload after the query like this `ip/?query=<image/src/onerror=prompt(8)>`

How can I tell if the prompt was successful and the payload is working?

Are there any hints in the source code or the HTTP request so i can now that the site is vulnerable to XSS?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Just doing a request and retrieving the resulting HTML source won't have executed the JavaScript (client-side) `prompt(8)` invocation.

You would need to use a browser to see if the code gets executed; in your case, probably a scriptable browser runner such as Playwright or Puppeteer.

Comment: are these for lua ?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine there are Lua bindings for them, no.

Comment: Oh , Ok thanks for your help :)